# apollo.watchQuery results in 'ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function'

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, apollo

I am currently working on some basic stuff with Angular (5) and GraphQL and I am running into some issues with calling calling the `watchQuery` method. Once i call the method my component crashes and returns me with the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

I have searched the web for a solution but i couldn't find a proper one. My environment contains the following libraries:

- apollo-angular: ^1.1.0
- apollo-angular-link-http: ^1.1.0
- apollo-cache-inmemory: ^1.2.2
- apollo-client: ^2.3.2
- graphql: ^0.13.2
- graphql-tag: ^2.9.2
- rxjs: ^5.5.6

I have a sharedModule with some of the imports and the link:

```
export class SharedModule {
  constructor(apollo: Apollo, httpLink: HttpLink) {
    apollo.create({
      link: httpLink.create({uri: 'baseUri/graphql'}),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
  }
}
```

And i have the following code inside my list component:

```
getMovies() {
  this.movies = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({    // <= where my error occurs
    query: gql`
      query {
        movies {
          id
          title
          genres
        }
      }
    `
  })
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(map((result) => result.data.movies));
}
```

the complete error contains the following lines up to my code:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
   at new QueryRef (QueryRef.js:6)
   at ApolloBase.watchQuery (Apollo.js:30)
   at MovieListComponent.getMovies (movie-list.component.ts:37)
   at MovieListComponent.ngOnInit (movie-list.component.ts:29)
```

If anyone has suggestions or questions, please let me know.

Comment: Have you maybe tried this minimal example? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html#rxjs Maybe you can take it from there...

Comment: Thnx! Wil look at it tomorrow at work.

Comment: Had the same issue and downgraded to v1.0.1 as suggested by @user3270598. This fixed it for us. Added an issue in the repo https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/issues/651

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular 5, this is likely because the versions you referenced in your question depend on RxJS 6. You have two solutions:

- Upgrade to Angular 6 *AND* RxJS 6
- Downgrade Apollo Angular packages to the 1.0.1 versions that depend on RxJS 5

Do not attempt to upgrade to RxJS 6 and stay at Angular 5, you will run into more issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to downgrade `grapqh` and `graphql-tag`

Comment: Which Versions would you recomended?

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because a mismatch between RxJS v5 and v6.

- Apollo v1.1.0 and newer support Angular 6+ and RxJS 6+
- Apollo prior v1.1.0 works on Angular 5 and RxJS 5.

If you encountered the issue, we highly recommend to upgrade to RxJS 6. We did in in couple of huge projects without any issues.

If you can't upgrade then stick to versions 1.0.X of apollo-angular.